# PHP foreach() is amending the array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

The following code which is displaying a value from within an array is presenting different results when wrapped in a foreach() as opposed to when I use a simple for-loop.  The for-loop is presenting the correct data but the foreach() appears to be amending the input array with every iteration.

```
$arr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);

for ($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++) {
    echo $arr[90]['circread_value'];
}

foreach ($arr as $unused) {
    echo $arr[90]['circread_value'];
}
```

The output from the for-loop is the same value over and over again (as expected):

```
1382429.00
1382429.00
1382429.00
1382429.00
...
```

The output from the foreach() shows that the 91st element in the array is changing with each iteration:

```
56256.00
45652.00
50726.00
317896.00
...
```

How can this be?

Note: I know the code above is contrived (obviously within the foreach() I'm actually wanting to do further processing and refer to each element of the array that I'm iterating through, not just look at the 91st element.)  I have simply pared back the code to something simple (as part of my debugging, as much as for posting here!)

Some further information:

- $arr has been created by array_merge'ing two 91-element arrays to create a 182 element array.
- The behaviour I see is only happening for the 91st element - if I echo out $arr[89]['circread_value'] or $arr[91]['circread_value'], I get consistent values from the foreach() too.
- The (seemingly random) values that I see in the foreach() are actually values from other elements in the array (the array as it looks prior to beginning the foreach)

The input arrays ($arr1 and $arr2) can be found here: http://pastebin.com/wQN8XXu2

Thanks for any insight. Don't hesitate to ask for further information.

Comment: Interesting. What is the output of `var_dump` for each loop iteration?

Comment: Are you saying you have run the *exact* code above with your data, and you see this issue?

Comment: I am [unable to repeat](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eHzDf2) this... PHP version please

Comment: @DaveRandom Yes - I've run this exact code.  Seems odd eh?  I'd jump to the "PHP must be buggy" but red-flags warn me that it's more likely to be my error!

Comment: @DaveRandom Note that there is more code (to set up the array etc - and it's part of a large site).  The array content is not exactly as I have shown here (as there are more sub-elements than just 'blah', and obviously there are a whole 182 elements to consider.)  I could send this to you?

Comment: I can't repeat this problem either. I also can't answer your question because you didn't post all relevant code.

Comment: If it is too large to post here, maybe create a [paste](http://pastebin.com/) of it?

Comment: Using PHP 5.3.6-13 (Ubuntu) btw.

Comment: Thanks @DaveRandom - I've done just that and updated the question with a link and very slightly revised code to put in the real name of array keys.

Comment: We've noticed that if we do the array_merge() the other way round - array_merge($arr2, $arr1) - then we get the same effect but on $arr[181]

Answer (score 0):

foreach modifies the internal array pointer, for doesn't, because it expects you to supply an integer offset, as evidenced here https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

"As foreach relies on the internal array pointer changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior."

Comment: `foreach modifies the internal array pointer` - No, it doesn't. `foreach` works with a copy of the array, which is why you as to use references (a la `foreach ($arr as &$val)`) in order to modify the source array. And it would be irrelevant here anyway, he is referencing the values statically.

Comment: Yes it does: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php. The thing is, it resets just one time, at the start of the loop. In this case, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @drgomesp I agree about this case, except "this case" looks like fiction as far as I can tell, and I thought I'd get to the root of whatever the actual error probably is in the real code (which this clearly isn't)

Comment: It appears to actually use the array pointer to perform the loop, not just reset it at the beginning.  Hence the warning about not messing with it in the loop.

Comment: @menacingly seriously, if your working with the actual array, why does [this](http://codepad.org/wehPXIkw) happen?

Comment: @DaveRandom, he is not talking about working with the actual array. What we are trying to say is exactly what is in the official docs. The pointer is reset at the first iteration of the loop. Period.

Comment: @DaveRandom I didn't say _you_ (the user) are working with the actual array.  PHP is.  It modifies the internal pointer of the array (that is stored within the array, hence the name) to keep a reference to where it is.  Thus, modifications to the original array variable by name (which he's doing) will have their pointer placed internally by the ongoing foreach call.

Comment: Again, the answer has a valid argument, but it is not correct for this case.

Comment: [That is apparently true](http://codepad.org/vq55bO6w) but in that case I don't get why [this](http://codepad.org/wehPXIkw) doesn't just loop forever...

Comment: @DaveRandom why should it loop forever?

Comment: @drgomesp Because a new item is pushed onto the end of the array on every iteration, so the pointer should never reach the end.

Comment: Like I said, the pointer is reset just at the first iteration. So it shouldn't loop forever.

Comment: Yes, but it advances that pointer on every iteration, and at the end of the foreach the pointer is at the end (as shown by [this](http://codepad.org/vq55bO6w)). So if you push a new item onto the array on each iteration, that pointer should never reach the end, because even if you are on the last element there will be another by the end of that iteration.

Comment: @DaveRandom that's really interesting. I guess for the iteration PHP just uses a copy reference of that array, like you said, but reset the original array's pointer one time anyways.

Comment: Indeed, that is my point, there is a bit of a grey area. Although I actually thought it worked with a completely separate copy of the array with it's own pointer, and that it seems is also not completely the case - although we have got somewhat off topic here since the array pointer is (theoretically) irrelevant to the OPs code anyway ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom "that pointer should never reach the end" <- good call.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your code brother.

I've just [tested this](http://codepad.org/vAPW75mq):

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array('blah' => 123.42),
    1 => array('blah' => 5488.87),
    90 => array('blah' => 669874.923)
);

for ($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++) {
    echo $arr[90]['blah'] . PHP_EOL;
}

foreach ($arr as $unused) {
    echo $arr[90]['blah'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

And it outputs fine:

```
669874.923
669874.923
669874.923
669874.923
669874.923
669874.923
```

Do you mind showing us a little more of your code?

Comment: Thanks - I will dump the entire content of the real array and post that shortly (the example array is not the exact array.)

Answer (score 0):

Problem found.  That 91st element of the array was actually a *reference* to the array.  The foreach was then using the same variable name (reference to the same array - named $unused in the example snippet I gave in the question) so both were looking at the same array.

We noticed the "&" in the array dump after posting it on here for you guys, so StackOverflow has helped our debug process... thanks for everyone's input.